JavaFX Vertical scroll bar always visible in VirtualFlow
I am encountering an issue with vertical scroll bar visibility when I set the height of a TableView to some fixed height. The vertical scroll bar is always visible.
I am trying to give enough space(height) so that the vertical scroll bar is not visible, but looks like this only works after some considerable value..(I mean around 14px or 15px). So assuming this might be an issue in VirtualFlow, I tested it on ListView and TreeView. And as expected, I can notice the same issue in those controls as well.
In the below picture, you can clearly see that there is enough space in viewport, and I am not expecting a vertical scroll bar. The strange part is that the vertical scroll bar appears with no active implementation, I mean I cannot move the bar thumb.

I can clearly say that this is a JavaFX Bug. Can any one let me know how can I fix this issue or workaround?
Note that this issue is very specific only if I fix the height of control. Things work as usual if the control is resized dynamically.
Other finding is that, this issue occurs only if the horizontal scroll bar is also visible.
Tested this on latest version of JavaFX (FX23 build 29)
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class VerticalScrollBarVisibilityIssueDemo extends Application {

    String CSS = "data:text/css,"+
            """
                    .list-cell:odd {
                        -fx-background: #AEAEAE;
                    }
                    .table-row-cell:odd {
                        -fx-background: #AEAEAE;
                    }
                    """;
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final VBox root = new VBox();
        root.setSpacing(10);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        final Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 350);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(CSS);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.setTitle("Vertical ScrollBar Visibility Issue " + System.getProperty("javafx.runtime.version"));
        stage.show();

        loadRoot(root);
    }

    private void loadRoot(VBox root) {
        TableView<List<String>> tableView = new TableView<>();
        tableView.setMaxHeight(120);
        VBox.setVgrow(tableView,Priority.ALWAYS);
        int colCount = 10;
        for(int i =0;i<colCount;i++){
            final int index = i;
            TableColumn<List<String>, String> column = new TableColumn<>("Option "+i);
            column.setCellValueFactory(param -> new ReadOnlyObjectWrapper<>(param.getValue().get(index)));
            tableView.getColumns().add(column);
        }
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
            List<String> row = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i =0;i<colCount;i++){
                row.add("Row"+j+"-Opt"+i);
            }
            tableView.getItems().add(row);
        }

        ListView<String> listView = new ListView<>();
        VBox.setVgrow(listView,Priority.ALWAYS);
        listView.setMaxWidth(200);
        listView.setMaxHeight(92);
        listView.getItems().addAll("Option 1 Big Text TestingOption 1 Big Text Testing", "Option 2","Option 3");

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<>();
        VBox.setVgrow(treeView,Priority.ALWAYS);
        treeView.setMaxWidth(200);
        treeView.setMaxHeight(92);
        TreeItem<String> rootItem = new TreeItem<>("Root");
        TreeItem<String> item1 = new TreeItem<>("Item 1");
        TreeItem<String> item1_1 = new TreeItem<>("Item 1_1");
        item1.getChildren().add(item1_1);
        TreeItem<String> item2 = new TreeItem<>("Item 2 Item 2 Item 2 Item 2 Item 2 ");
        TreeItem<String> item3 = new TreeItem<>("Item 3");
        rootItem.getChildren().addAll(item1, item2, item3);
        treeView.setRoot(rootItem);
        treeView.setShowRoot(false);

        root.getChildren().addAll(tableView,listView,treeView);
    }
}


Probably best to report as a bug

@jewelsea I am trying to report.. but it is not allowing me to do so.. after entering all the details and when i click submit.. it says access denied :(

Such is life I guess.  If you are interested in continuing to pursue it, then you could try posting to the openjfx-dev mailing list.

Ok.. will post in the mailing list
